# CNTK absolute error

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, cntk

To find the loss during training a model we can use `cntk.squared_error()` function, like this:

```
loss = cntk.squared_error(z, l)
```

But I am interested in finding the loss in terms of absolute error. The below code doesn't work:

```
loss = cntk.absolute_error(z, l)
```

It gives error as:

> AttributeError: module 'cntk' has no attribute 'absolute_error'

Is there any inbuilt function in CNTK toolkit to find the absolute error? I am new to deep learning so I don't know much. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no out-of-the-box L1 loss function in CNTK, but you can provide a custom one:

```
def absolute_error(z, l):
  return cntk.reduce_mean(cntk.abs(z - l))
```

Comment: Looks cool, but I get some pretty funny results. I have a small dataset on which I run the squared_error. This gives me a value of `5.8343764679341374`. Now when I use the absolute_error function above, I get the value `17.3852909909019` for the same data samples. Which is weird in my opinion. Squared should be much higher.